# Show is a Markov Chain (Markov Property)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Resnick states:
If $\{X_n\}$ is Markov with stationary distribution $\pi$, show that $(X_n,X_{n+1}), (n\geq 0)$ is Markov. Give its stationary distribution.

I've already proved that $\{(X_n, Y_n)\}$ where $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are two independent Markov chains is Markov.
However, here $X_{n}, X_{n+1}$ are dependent on each other so I don't understand why $(X_{n}, X_{n+1})$ is Markov.

Attempt:
\begin{align*}
&P((X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}, X_{n+2}=i_{n+2}) \mid (X_{0}=i_0, X_{1}=i_{1}),...(X_n=i_n, X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}))\\
&\mbox{I can't multiply anything since I don't have independence}, X_{n+1} \mbox{is not independent of} X_{n+2}\\
&=P((X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}, X_{n+2}=i_{n+2}) \mid (X_{n}=i_n, X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}))
\end{align*}
Can I just say the last step since $X_{n+1}$ just depends on $X_n$ and $X_{n+2}$ just depends on $X_{n+1}$ by Markov Property?

Comment: The Markov property can be interpreted as the characteristic of the chain that says that the next state only depends on the current state and not on all the possible paths that allow reaching that current state. It is important to emphasize the concept of "possible paths".

Answer (score 1):

I leave the *precise* details to you -- doing these questions yourself is by far the best way to learn -- but let me give you the *ideas* behind the proof of the Markov property.

Consider $(X_n, X_{n+1})$ given the whole history $X_0, ..., X_n$. (Note that knowing $(X_0, X_1), (X_1, X_2), ..., (X_{n-1}, X_n)$ is equivalent to knowing $X_0, ..., X_n$.)
Clearly the first element of the pair $(X_n, X_{n+1})$ is determined by $X_n$ alone! And to get the second, by the Markov property, we only need to know $X_n$. So in fact the pair $(X_n, X_{n+1})$ is determined by knowledge of $X_n$ only, and so in particular by knowledge of $(X_{n-1}, X_n)$.

Hopefully this helps you to make a rigorous proof!